# Integration of dirac function explanation

Tags: integration, discrete-mathematics, convolution, image-processing

I have a problem that need your help. I have a gray image. We denotes $I(x)$ is gray level of a pixel in the image and $f(z)$ is a function of $z$(ie: histogram function...)-where $z$ is the set of gray level values in the set {1, 2, ..., 256} in $Z$, $\delta(.)$ is as smooth Gaussian kernel. The $V$ function is express as below figure. Hence I have a two questions that need you explain:

1. The $V$ function can express as convolution $V=(\delta*f)(I(x))$, **Is it right**?
2. Please explain the $V$ formula. **What does this mean?** As  my knowledge, assume that $f(z)$ is histogram of gray level 1 to 256. and $\delta(z-I(x)$ is dirac function at point $x$, hence the multiply of $\delta(z-I(x)$ and $f(z)$ will return a narrow distribution around the pixel $x$. The integrate of them that means we will do it for every gray level in $Z$ domain.  Hence, $V$ return a narrow distribution of set of gray level around the pixel $x$. **Is it correct?**

Paper reference: http://jgmalcolm.com/pubs/others/rathi_seeing_unseen.pdf

[image]

Update: The implementation:
Assume  $f(z)$ can denotes f_z=[0.01 0.02 ..0.001] with size 256x1, Image I is 3x3 the V function can implement as

```
V=f_z(I+1) %where I is image and f_z size is 256x1 - hence V size is 3x3
```

Please check my implementation is correct or not?

```
I=[1 1 2; 256 1 2; 256 256 256];
```

So the result is

```
V=[0.01 0.01 0.02; 0.001 0.01 0.02; 0.001 0.001 0.001]
```

Comment: Just to save my time, where is integral in the paper?

Comment: @almagest: Formula (7) page 2.

Comment: Ah, thanks. So $K()=\delta$ and it is the integral immediately above section 3. at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Right. I only make a short expression

Comment: Two people now have confirmed your understanding. Some of the images in the paper are quite startling. I guess I do not understand why some things work so well and others not. I know nothing about the Bhattacharyya distance, but it looks like a "classical statistics" concept. I thought it was established in the 1970s that Bayesian methods worked much better than classical statistics ones.

Comment: @almagest: Thank you for your information. Do you know other distance that better than Bhattacharyya. I am finding the other distance as K-L distance or Eart distance. But it is similar with Bhattacharyya  distance result

Comment: Sorry. I cannot help you further. But some friends of mine at the Cavendish Lab in Cambridge Univ (UK) did the work on the Bayesian approach. It was critical in helping to win acceptance for Bayesian approach. Classical statistics holds some kind of record for the longest acceptance period in modern times of a fundamentally incorrect theory.

Comment: Yes. I spent 1 month to implementing that algorithm by matlab code. But it cannot achieve the results the paper report. The algorithm was published in IEEE, so it is very complex and I am not sure about paper result

Comment: Published results are often wrong. Whether it is worth putting effort into correcting them is another matter. I remember going to a seminar at the Cavendish a while back. It seemed like bunk to me. I remarked to my host on the way to the coffee that it was not quite right, but he had not said anything. He replied, "Of course not, why should I help him?" The opposing C tradition was to try to reduce the speaker to tears by tearing his work apart!

Comment: You already listened that algorithm in that seminar. I remember that the author name is Dr.  Oleg Michailovich. I found some paper refer to that paper. But all papers did not publish source code.

Comment: The seminar was not relevant to your topic. I agree with you that the results look surprisingly good. I was just commenting that correcting others' mistakes is not always a good use of one's own time. Of course, one has a duty to be helpful sometimes. :)

Answer (score 1):

> The $V$ function can be expressed as convolution $V=(\delta*f)(I(x))$, is that right?

Yes, that's correct.  Furthermore, since $\delta * f = f$ for any function $f$, this integral gives us exactly 
$$
V = \int_{\mathcal Z} \delta(z - I(x)) \cdot f(z)\,dz = (\delta*f)(I(x)) = f(I(x))
$$
So, it is not just "a narrow distribution of set of gray level around the pixel $x$".  It is, in fact, exactly the value of the gray level at that pixel.

This, however, assumes that $\delta$ is precisely the Dirac-delta distribution.  Using approximations (such as the $\delta_\epsilon$ in the paper) gives us a weighted average of the values of $f$ nearby that approaches $f(I(x))$ as $\epsilon \to 0$.

Comment: Thank sir. So assume that $f(z)$ return a vector (histogram distribtution) as $f(z)$={0.01 0.02 ..0.001} that means $f(I(1))=0.01$,$f(I(2))=0.02$...$f(I(256))=0.001$. Right?

Comment: Yes, as far as I understand

Comment: @Omnomnommon: Thank you, I see. I have more information about $f(z)$ if $\delta$ is a approximations function. Therefore, $V$ will become $f(I(x)$?What is meaning of "left unsmoothed distributions". Let see formula (9) and (10) in the paper http://jgmalcolm.com/pubs/malcolm_lsdm.pdf

Answer (score 1):

$I(x)$ is the gray value at the pixel $x$; $f(z)$ is some unspecified function of the gray value (it could be a histogram frequency, but that's unsure). $V$ is a function of $x$ taking values in the image of $f$.

Has $\delta$ denoted a Dirac delta, you would have had $$V(x)=f(I(x)),$$
i.e. take the gray level at $x$, let $z=I(x)$, and compute $f(z)$.

In the case of a (narrow) Gaussian, instead of $f(z)$, you will compute an average of $f$ in the vicinity of $z=I(x)$, i.e. a moothed version of $f$.

If $f$ is indeed the histogram of image $I$, the final $V$ output will show the frequency of the pixels in $I$, i.e. bright values for the most common gray scales (usually the background).

Comment: Could you check my implementation- Is it correct? I am using matlab

Comment: Post it on Code Review.

Comment: You said that if $K(.)$ denotes in the paper is Gaussian, instead of $\delta$, so it becomes convolution problem. V(x)=(K*f)(x) Right?

Comment: Yes, just check the formula for a convolution. When one of the functions is a Gaussian, the convolution is a lowpass (smoothing) filter.